# Docker link container as build argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've a Docker composer file similar to:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        volumes:
            - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_DATABASE: test
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    test:
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db:db
        build:
            context: .
            args:
                MYSQL_HOST: db
                MYSQL_DATABASE: test
                MYSQL_USER: test
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        restart: always
```

Inside test container Dockerfile

```
FROM ...

...
ARG MYSQL_HOST 127.0.0.1

RUN set -x; echo $MYSQL_HOST

RUN script ... --param $MYSQL_HOST
```

However `MYSQL_HOST` variable (which I would expect to be the internal IP of the other container) is not being translated into the other container name.

How could it be done? Can it be achieved in another way with docker-compose?

Comment: What value does MYSQL_HOST contain?

Comment: MYSQL_HOST should refer to the hostname/IP of the other container...

Comment: Ok, but what does it contain **now**, with your current composer file?

Comment: You can see above:  
<pre>           
...
args:
                MYSQL_HOST: db
</pre>

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want a build argument here. Would probably set MYSQL_HOST as an environment variable. Inside of docker-compose, the literal string `db` is actually resolvable to your db container.

Typically, compose files look like this:

```
test:
   links:
     db:db
   environment:
     - MYSQL_HOST=db
```

Then in your test code do something like:

```
...
String dbHost = System.getEnv("MYSQL_HOST");
...
```

That way, the MySql host doesn't need to be built into your image removing the need for your image to be rebuilt all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly that code is in already existing application and it's actually used in the building process for generating a configuration file to be read by the running application (this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Install.php). It seems it must be with build args, because envs are ignored in the build process.

Comment: It sounds like your build depends on external network access to another container. By design, images should be able to be built on any docker hosts without external dependencies, and docker doesn't really support the method you require to gather dependencies. At best, you could have a pre-build step that gathers settings from external sources and injects those directly into the image build as args.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I actually can do this with a Bash script command such as: "docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' db` I will comment in docker-compose issues if this may be a possibility in the future...